# Perl: Delete multiple lines from text file having a specific string

Tags: perl

I have a text file having data in below mentioned format..

```
@rectype='ABC' @recname='123'   @rec_id='1K2j' etc...
@rectype='DEF' @recname='matin' @rec_id='458i' etc...
@rectype='ABC' @recname='John'  @rec_id='lom0' etc...
@rectype='GHI' @recname='Kalme, @rec_id='pl90' etc...
@rectype='KLM' @recname='Kitty' @rec_id='987k' etc...
@rectype='ABC' @recname='OMR'   @rec_id='lo09' etc...
```

Now, I have to delete all the lines having @rectype='ABC'..there are multiple lines of this kind in the input file.It's a kind of urgent and as I am not a perl coder , I am finding it difficult to figure out the way.

Please suggest!!!

NOTE: I need to make changes in input file only. I don't need to create a seperate output file.

Comment: `grep -v "@rectype='ABC'"`?

Comment: I do not see why this answer was downvoted. It is a very simple and elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my $output = 'output.txt';
open my $outfile, '>', $output or die "Can't write to $output: $!";

my @array = read_file('input.txt');
for (@array){
        next if ($_ =~ /^\@rectype='ABC'/);     
        print $outfile $_ ;
}
```

Output (saved to 'output.txt'):

```
@rectype='DEF' @recname='matin' @rec_id='458i' etc...
@rectype='GHI' @recname='Kalme, @rec_id='pl90' etc...
@rectype='KLM' @recname='Kitty' @rec_id='987k' etc...
```

Comment: as i do need to update the input file after making the changes, rather than creating a new output file. So, should i use print $_ only in place of $outfile $_ ??

Comment: Print $_ will print to the command line. use: `my $output = 'input.txt';
open my $outfile, '>>', $output or die "Can't write to $output: $!";`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do it in Perl.  You can use the `grep` tool.

```
grep -v "@rectype='ABC'" input_file > output_file
```

`grep -v` means "Print every line that does not match this expression."

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -ne 'print if !/\@rectype = \047ABC\047/x' text_file
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of a single quote collision. One option is to use its octal value, as: `...\047ABC\047/'`

Comment: @TLP sometimes double quotes doesn't work (can't remember when exactly :) )

Comment: It will try and interpolate shell variables, so you have to escape dollar signs, which gets confusing sometimes.

Comment: @mpapec, Using double-quotes mean you need to escape `$`, `\ ` and possibly others. I stick to single-quotes, and use `'\''` when I need a single quote.

Comment: @ikegami tnx for hint